# Why the inputs from my website not work on Iphone devices?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, input

i am work in a personal project, is the first time that i tested my web on Iphone devices, unfortunately i see that the inputs from my forms in all my project not work in this kind of devices, the text does not appear.

I proved it using touch events in my javascript code, but it still the same, so i decided don't use this events anymore.
I have tested my web on Mozilla, Chrome, Opera, even Safary on desktop devices and it works fine, but only Iphone the inputs not work, the text don't writte on it.

Here is a piece of my code:

HTML:

```
<input class='campo' type='text' name='MJT_username' required autocomplete='off' placeholder='Username' onfocus='label(this,"#l5")' title='Insert your username'>
```

CSS:

```
.campo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 5px 5px 20px 0px;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: var(--white);
    outline: none;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 35px;
    background-color: var(--grey-color);
}
```

JS:

```
function label(e,label){
    var lab = document.querySelector(label);
    var plac = e.placeholder;
    e.placeholder = "";
    e.style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 0 0.4px var(--verde)";
    e.style.borderRadius = "3px";
    lab.style.opacity="1";
    e.addEventListener('focusout', function(){
        if (e.value != "") {
            lab.style.opacity="1";
        }
        else {
            e.style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 0px 0px transparent";
            e.placeholder = lab.innerText;
            e.style.borderRadius = "3px";
            lab.style.opacity="0";
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks for your help.
PD: Sorry for bad english.

Comment: Please provide more detail than 'doesn't work'. What are you expecting to happen? What does actually happen? Is the input not rendered? Can you type in it? Is the JS event being fired?

Comment: After I started using JQuery, my problems with iPhone devices disappeared.